# How to accept and close a question?

Tags: support

I am new to this site and need to know about closing the request.
How do we close our question once the answer is received?

Comment: Being answered isnt a reason to close a question. You accept by clicking on the empty checkmark by the answer. That'll turn it green. But the question should remain open.

Comment: The help center is usually a good place to find answers to these types of questions: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Closing questions is reserved for questions that shouldn't have been posted to begin with.

Comment: What @MarkRotteveel is trying to say is that "closing" a question has an entirely different meaning in StackOverflow . Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)... What you want to do is accept the answer which you find correct.. (Click on the tick). You dont need to close a question

Comment: We don't have a concept of "this question no longer receives answers", which is what I *think* you are asking for. One reason is that a question could always get a new and better answer in the future, so disallowing that is seen as counter productive.

Comment: Thanks for  all your comments and is well understood

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We don't close questions here when they're answered, we just [mark the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) as "accepted". That's all you need to do to indicate that you've resolved your situation.

Closure on Stack Exchange sites is used for questions that cannot or should not be answered -- and generally leads to deletion.

We accept the possibility that an answered question may eventually attract a new solution, or a better explanation, or just an alternative, and leave it open for new answers to be posted.

Comment: Really surprised this isn't a dupe here; these are on MSE: [How mark my question as answered on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147531) [Set my own question as solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96395)